# FIPS and Python 2.5.4 - How to set ciphers?

Tags: ssl, python-2.5, fips

In the later python releases there is an SSL Wrapper that allows the setting of the cipher being used.

```
ssl.wrap_socket(...)
```

or

```
SSLContext.
```

Is there a way of doing it in Python 2.5.4 that has to be FIPS compliant? (successfully linked with the appropriate SSL library)

Wanted ciphers:

```
TLSv1.2+FIPS:kRSA+FIPS:!eNULL:!aNULL
```

current: default?

---

I did find the following:
https://pypi.python.org/pypi/ssl/
but didnt see an option to set the wanted cipher.

Comment: It is unlikely that you have a Python 2.5.4 which supports TLS 1.2. TLS 1.2 is supported since OpenSSL 1.0.1 which was released in 2012. Python 2.5.4 was released 2008 and the version current at the time of OpenSSL offering TLS 1.2 was 2.7.3.

Comment: I have a locally compiled Python 2.5.4 that links with the proper SSL library

Comment: @SteffenUllrich alternatively, is there a code somewhere that defines the cipher list in the python 2.5.4 sources? for instance __hash_new in hahlib.py there is __hash_new that returns a new hashing object according to the named algorithm. just for ciphers?

Comment: The implemented ciphers are buried inside the linked OpenSSL library and as far as I know there is no way to access these from Python. But you can do a packet capture and look at the TLS handshake ClientHello to see what ciphers are offered by the client.